# PowerShell move file name with same time frame creation time

Tags: date, powershell, move, creation

I am trying to create script that will move files in different folders based on file creation date and time bracket ( 5 minutesw increment) . Here an example on what I want to achieve:

### Files  within forlder Source:

File1 - creation date&time: 2016-11-23 8:00AM
File2 - creation date&time: 2016-11-23 8:01AM
File3 - creation date&time: 2016-11-23 8:02AM
File4 - creation date&time: 2016-11-23 8:10AM
File5 - creation date&time: 2016-11-23 8:11AM
File6 - creation date&time: 2016-11-23 8:12AM

Script will move file1,2,3 in on folder1 and file 4,5,6 on fodler2 given the fact that file 4,5,6 have a creation date increment > 5 minutes than file1,2,3

I started working with Get-ChildItem but having issues/question on how to script that 5 minutes increment notion.

Any help is appreciate since this is my first day scripting in PowerShell

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$path = your-path
$searchDate = Get-Date -Date "2016-11-23 08:00:00"

for($i=1; $i -le 10; $i++)
{
    Get-ChildItem -Path $path -recurse -include "$Include" |
        where {$_.CreationTime -ge $searchDate.AddMinutes(($i-1)*5) -and 
               $_.CreationTime -lt $searchDate.AddMinutes($i*5)
        }
}
```

Comment: Ok, and where does the move function somes into play - thanks

Comment: @DidierLaplante you didn't mention where to move the files.

Comment: move to: $destination1: 'c:/temp/folder1"  , $destination2: 'c:/temp/folder2" - so on

Answer (score 0):

if you want move files in dirs by range of 5 minutes creation time

```
$direresult="c:\temp9\"

#list file with creation of property rang
$listfile=gci "c:\temp" -recurse -file | sort creationtime | select  Name, fullname, creationtime, @{N="Rang";E={0}}

#load in value rang next if condition is respected
$cpt=1

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $listfile.Count; $i++)
{ 
    if ($i -lt ($listfile.Count-1))
    {
        if ($listfile[$i+1].creationtime -gt $listfile[$i].creationtime.AddMinutes(5)) {$cpt++}
        $($listfile[$i+1]).Rang=$cpt
    }
}

#move files by group
$rangfile=0
$listfile | group  Rang | %{$rangfile++; New-Item -ItemType Directory "$direresult\folder$rangfile" -Force; $_.group | %{move-item $_.fullname "$direresult\folder$rangfile" -Force   }       }
```

Comment: Hello, it seems to be working ok as far as moving files is concerned. However on my test, it only moved the first file of a sequence to folder1 and the rest of the files in folder2 regardless of date/time creation. Note that in my test all files should have been move to fodler 1 as they are from same 5 minutes creation time. - thx